# Confused about why hashsum, encode, print is different then write, hashum, encode, print in Go?

Tags: go, cryptography

Sorry about the title. I couldn't come up with a better way of phrasing my question and will change it happily if somebody else can.

Hasher is defined with

```
hasher := md5.New()
```

Anyway, I am curious why this:

```
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum([]byte(input))))
```

gives me 6869d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e, while this:

```
hasher.Write([]byte(input))
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
```

gives me 49f68a5c8493ec2c0bf489821c21fc3b
and this:

```
fmt.Printf("%x\n", md5.Sum([]byte(input)))
```

gives me 49f68a5c8493ec2c0bf489821c21fc3b.

Comment: you should show how you got/defined `hasher`, it doesn't google well

Comment: @DanielFarrell Edited per your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `hasher.Sum()` **does not** hash the passed slice. The passed slice is used as the *destination*: it appends the current hash to it and does not change the underlying hash state. `hasher.Write()` obviously includes the passed slice in the hash calculation. The 2 examples are fundamentally different, the different results are nothing but expected.

Always read the documentation. [`hash.Hash.Sum()`](https://pkg.go.dev/hash#Hash):

> ```
> // Sum appends the current hash to b and returns the resulting slice.
> // It does not change the underlying hash state.
> Sum(b []byte) []byte
> ```

So when you first call `hasher.Sum()`, whatever you pass to it, it doesn't matter in terms of the result hash. If you haven't written anything into `hasher` previously, you'll see the initial hash.

When you next call `hasher.Write([]byte(input))`, you'll write the bytes of `input` into the hasher, so when you call `hasher.Sum(nil)` next, you'll see the calculated hash of `input`. Since you pass `nil`, a new slice will be allocated to accommodate the result.

When you again call `hasher.Write([]byte(input))`, as previously written: this won't change the hash state, the passed slice is not used as input, but only as the destination for "returning" the result, the current hash value. So you will get the same hash value as you got from the previous `hasher.Sum(nil)` call. Obviously, if the passed slice does not have enough capacity to store the result, a new one will be allocated / used.

See this complete, runnable example which reproduces your output:

```
input := "hi"
hasher := md5.New()
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum([]byte(input))))

hasher.Write([]byte(input))
fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil)))

fmt.Printf("%x\n", md5.Sum([]byte(input)))
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fx9WEM027P2).

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realized that the argument to sum was the destination. I was very confused looking at the md5 documentation when I should've looked at the hash documentation!

Comment: @minzi Yes, it may be somewhat confusing because there is a `md5.Sum()` function which does calculate the hash of the passed slice. It's a "shorthand" for creating a hasher, writing the slice into it and calling the hasher's `Sum()` method.